# How to extract data in Quotes from a string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have timestamps in the shape of a csv file where each string looks like:

```
TT_TU_MN009,"5009","200001010000","-1.8","3","4"
TT_TU_MN009,"5009","200001010200","-1.7","10","1"
TT_TU_MN009,"5009","200001011400","1","10","1"
...
```

My goal is to extract the second, third and forth position from this string (without the double quotes) into its own column:

- 5009
- 200001010000
- -1.8

I managed to achieve this for the first column

```
=LEFT(A2;SEARCH(",";A2)-1)
```

but have no idea how to do it for the other 2 positions. Is that without VBA achievable?

Thank you in advance

A

Comment: How are you bringing the csv into Excel?

Comment: it came as a download, these are historic temperature values from a meteo station

Comment: This does not answer my question. If you open the CSV in Excel, it should automatically deal with the quotes.

Comment: No, the data have been provided as a string but in an excel file, all the data are sitting in the A column as a string in the excel sheet

Comment: Ah, so then it is *not* a CSV. `Data -> Text to Columns` Choose "Delimited" on "Commas", then do a search and replace to remove the quotes

Comment: No, that’s not a solution, I’ve tried this and it somehow does produce errors in some fields, I’m specifically looking for the formula to extract these values.

Comment: Works fine for me, what errors are you getting? If it's the formatting of the third column, you need to fix that with cell format

Comment: Im rather looking to get something like this working:  https://exceljet.net/formula/split-text-with-delimiter

Comment: Use text to columns with comma delimiter and force the columns as text in the forth step.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  @cybernetic.nomad offered good advice, it **is** a solution for the dataset you provided and it is likely most of us would use text to columns ourselves.  That said, you want to look into PowerQuery.  It is **the** solution for what you are doing. Split the column at the first `,"` and take everything to the right.  Then split column with a three character delimiter `","`  replace the trailing `"` on the fifth column.  You'll have a nice clean table and you can refresh it with the click of a button when you import be data.  Trust me, this is the way you want to go.

Comment: @aerioeus,,did your output are in one Cell or in separate Cells?

Comment: @aerioeus, I think you can consider cybernetic.nomad's suggestion. Or you can try copy the file into .txt file, then import it to Excel, choose comma delimiter.

Comment: thanks for the options guys, but as said, I would prefer the transparent version to the build-in conversion. merci anyway for the suggestions ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would like to suggest two different methods to extract nth text from Text string in Cell.*

**Method 1:**

[image]

- Formula in cell `J16`:

  ```
  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("""" & $J$13& REPT(" ",6),"""",REPT(CHAR(32),255)),2*255,255))
  ```

**N.B.**

- `2*255` determines the position of the text, in `J13`, `5009` is 2nd word/text.
- For `20000101000` the position is 4th since formula counts `,` before it as 3rd one, so for formula in cell `J17` replace `2*255` with `4*255` and with `6*255` for `-1.8` formula in `J18`.

---

**Method 2:**

It comprises VBA macro, is an UDF(User Define function).

- Press either **Alt+F11** or **R**ight Click the **S**heet TAB & from poped up menu hit **View Code** to get VB editor.
- **C**opy & **P**aste this code as Module.

---

```
    Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)

    Dim arr() As String
    arr = VBA.Split(Source, ",")
    xCount = UBound(arr)
    If xCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xCount Or Position < 0 Then
     FindWord = ""
     Else
     FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
    End If
    End Function
```

---

[image]

- Formula in Cell `J3`: `=SUBSTITUTE(J1,CHAR(34),"")`
- Enter this formula in cell `J5`: `=FindWord(J3,2)`

**N.B.**

- In this formula `2` determines 2nd word/text in cell so that next  would be `=FindWord(J3,3)` and so on.

**You may use CONCATENATION if need all in one cell.**

Comment: Super Rajesh, thats what I was looking for! many thanks. is there a chance you could explain the first solution a bit more so I can adjust it later if needed? Besides; I would like to replace the "dot" in the last value (Temperatur) - like "1.9" with a comma since we use it differently in Europe (like this "1,9". could you be so kind and adjust the formula in this regard? That would be awesome. merci

Comment: I would like to replace it like this but have it all in one formula:

`=SUBSTITUTE(K2;".";",")`

Comment: @aerioeus,, no need to worry about if & when another number format is been used `1,8` instead of `1.8`, formula will return what so ever it's is ,, you get `1,8`☺

Comment: I understand that, but this conversion is mandatory since the format given is `1.8` but in the end I need `1,8` - thats cause the provided data uses the "dot" but for further calculations I need the "comma" ;)

Comment: Daer @aerioeus,,, exactly the same I was trying to say ,, you replace `1.8` with `1,8` in `J13` then try the same `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("""",,,` formula I've suggested in Cell `J18`,, will return `1,8` ☺

Comment: Dear @Rajesh S, no thats not what I mean: the data in J13 contain `1.8` so if I apply your formula to the string in `J13` it will effictively return `1.8` since the original string contains the value `1.8`.
But for further calculations I need to convert this value into `1,8` since. This differs from the source string. Thats why I need to add this conversion to  your formula or else I need to do this conversion from `1.8` to `1,8` in a 2 step process ...

Comment: @aerioeus,, if I'm not wrong, You need to change Excel's defaults all about using `,` instead of `.` .

Comment: hi @Rajesh  no, the settings are fine. look the stringt looks like this:
`TT_TU_MN009,"430","201909062300","11.1","0","1"` - no matter what setting I choose. So I can only extract `11.1` - but I need `11,1` - thats why I created the substitute formula afterwards. Just want to combine both...

Comment: @aerioeus,, you may use this `=TEXT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("""" & $J$13& REPT(" ",6),"""",REPT(CHAR(32),255)),6*255,255)),"#,#")` . Need to use TEXT for Number Format,, please confirm through comments the I'll edit my post to add this Formula !!

Comment: HI @Rajesh, unfortunately that doesnt work.

Comment: @aerioeus,, I'm surprised ,, possibly we are unable to understand the issue otherwise all I suggested you are 100% working, I always test before I post here,, anyways pls find my Mail ID with profile,,, & mail me single sheet sample data & expected result I'll solve it ☺

Comment: merci @Rajesh, thats very generous of you, I will sent it to you.